# Symfony - Combine two properties in a single entity form field

Tags: forms, symfony, entity, symfony-2.3

I have an entity for publications with many different fields as booktitle, conference etc. I want to build a search form and one of the feature requests is to combine two search parameters in a single choice field. So far I have something like this in the form builder:

```
$builder->add('booktitle', 'entity', array(
              'required' => false, 
              'label' => 'Conference/Booktitle',
              'property' => 'booktitle',
              'class' => 'indPubBundle:Publication', 
              'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                     return $er->createQueryBuilder('p')
                               ->groupBy('p.booktitle')
                               ->orderBy('p.booktitle', 'ASC');
                      }
              ));
```

Basically I am displaying all booktitles as a choice field. What I want now is to have the conferences as well **in the same** choice field. Is there a way to achieve that?

Comment: Research data transformers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Entity field type is a child of the Choice field type. So you can provide Data via the "choices" parameter. Combine that with a (e.g. repository) method that returns an array with the data you need might be a solution that works for you.

```
$builder->add('booktitle', 'entity', array(
            'required' => false,
            'label' => 'Conference/Booktitle',
            'class' => 'indPubBundle:Publication',
            'choices' => $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('indPubBundle:Publication')->getData(),
        ));
```

Comment: I thought about that but unfortunately I don't have access to Doctrine from within the AbstractType class. I could hand over the Repo as an input parameter I guess, but I read somewhere that this would be very "not-Symfony-like". Do you think it will still be OK?

Comment: Yes, you could add the Repository (or Manager) to the Type options (there is a reason those exist!). Alternative is to use the formtype for the rest of the form and in the controller just add the new entity field to the form. That is usually how you do the buttons for example. More Symfony-Like.

Comment: I just found out, that instead of using `$this->getDoctrine()` you can use `$this->doctrine`. So I don't have to pass the an option to the Type.